# IBM DB2 Pyodbc String parameters issue: The invocation of routine "YEAR" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I'm using IBM Db2 ,and pyodbc.

insert_sql:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME
SELECT 
((YEAR('1/1/9999')*12+MONTH('1/1/9999')) - DOUBLE(YEAR(CYCL)*12+MONTH(CYCL)))
...
```

I want to replace '1/1/9999' with a parameter in python code so I used '?' to replace it:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME
SELECT 
((YEAR(?)*12+MONTH(?)) - DOUBLE(YEAR(CYCL)*12+MONTH(CYCL)))
```

Python:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(database_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(insert_sql,'1/1/9999','1/1/9999')
cnxn.commit()
```

Error:

```
The invocation of routine "YEAR" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.
```

Any friend can help ?

Comment: which database system are you using

Comment: @nbk IBM Db2 I forgot to mention

Comment: The problem seems to be that `YEAR()` has different behaviors depending on the datatype of the argument. But when you prepare a statement it doesn't know what the eventual datatype will be, so it doesn't know which variant of the function to call.

Comment: i believe this would be a good as an issue https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues